# angular2 ngOnChanges not working for multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on this angular2 app in which I am accepting two inputs in one component.

I have used ngOnChanges to detect changes on these input values.

```
@Input() games: any;
@Input() selectedGame:any;

ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {    
    this.selectedGame=changes['selectedGame'].currentValue;  //this works
    this.games=changes['games'].currentValue;    //this doesn't work
}
```

However, I can only detect change in first variable. the second variable is not getting updated when its value changes in parent.

any inputs?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in Plunker?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the change from the parent component, ngOnChanges might be triggered separately for each Input changed. You need to check which Input has changed first.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChange}) {   
    if(changes['selectedGame'] !== undefined)
        this.selectedGame=changes['selectedGame'].currentValue;

    if(changes['games'] !== undefined)
        this.games=changes['games'].currentValue;
}
```

Here's the working plunk
https://plnkr.co/edit/n6X21VHXw1xlA8XCPoQu

Answer (score 2):

You supposed to use `SimpleChanges` instaed of `SimpleChange`, it will give you all list of input parameters.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
 for (let propName in changes) {  
   let change = changes[propName];
   let curVal  = JSON.stringify(change.currentValue);
   let prevVal = JSON.stringify(change.previousValue);

    console.log(curVal);
    console.log(prevVal);
 }
}
```